# Writing to existing excel table using oledb - C#

Tags: c#, oledb

Currently I'm using this code:

```
private void WriteExcelFile()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [table1] (id INT, name VARCHAR, datecol DATE );";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(1,'AAAA','2014-01-01');";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

It will work if there is not `table1`, it will create it then insert the target row. But When I delete the Create table command and use just inserting, it won't work and say me that `table1` already exists. How to insert rows to an existing table (sheet) at the end (append row) using oldeb?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you [can do this using oledb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15894628/495455), however oledb can't do much more. Perhaps consider using Excel Interop or ClosedXML

Answer (score 2):

I suggest NOPI , which is in my opinion better than EPPlus

The Sample code for converting datatable to excel is here

```
public class ExcelTools
{
    public static byte[] WriteExcel(DataTable dtExport, string[] header = null, string[] excludeColumns = null, bool rtl = true)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            ISheet sheet = null;
            //-----------Create Style And Font
            var hFont = xssfWorkbook.CreateFont();
            hFont.FontHeightInPoints = 11;
            hFont.FontName = "Tahoma";
            var defaultStyle = xssfWorkbook.CreateCellStyle();
            defaultStyle.SetFont(hFont);
            var defaultHeaderStyle = xssfWorkbook.CreateCellStyle();
            defaultHeaderStyle.FillBackgroundColor = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.BlueGrey.Index;
            defaultHeaderStyle.SetFont(hFont);
            if (xssfWorkbook.NumberOfSheets == 0)
            {
                sheet = xssfWorkbook.CreateSheet(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtExport.TableName) ? "ExportReport" : dtExport.TableName);
                sheet.IsRightToLeft = true;
                sheet.CreateRow(0);
            }
            if (header != null)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < header.Length; index++)
                {
                    var strHeader = header[index];
                    sheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(index).SetCellValue(header[index]);
                    sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(index).CellStyle = defaultHeaderStyle;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtExport.Columns)
                {
                    if (excludeColumns != null && excludeColumns.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                        continue;
                    sheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(index).SetCellValue(col.ColumnName);
                    index++;
                }

            }


            sheet = xssfWorkbook.GetSheetAt(0);
            int indexRow = sheet.LastRowNum + 1;

            for (; indexRow < dtExport.Rows.Count + 1; indexRow++)
            {
                sheet.CreateRow(indexRow);
                int index = 0;
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtExport.Columns)
                {
                    if (excludeColumns != null && excludeColumns.Contains(col.ColumnName))
                        continue;
                    sheet.GetRow(indexRow).CreateCell(index).SetCellValue(dtExport.Rows[indexRow - 1][col.ColumnName].ToStringTD());
                    sheet.GetRow(indexRow).GetCell(index).CellStyle = defaultStyle;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < sheet.GetRow(0).Cells.Count; index++)
            {
                sheet.AutoSizeColumn(index);
            }
            xssfWorkbook.Write(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oledb is not as flexible, you can use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library instead.

Here is example.

```
using(var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\tmp.xlsx")))
{
   // calculate all formulas in the workbook
   package.Workbook.Calculate();
   // calculate one worksheet
   package.Workbook.Worksheets["my sheet"].Calculate();
  // calculate a range
  package.Workbook.Worksheets["my sheet"].Cells["A1"].Calculate();
}
```

Comment: I' using `.Net framework 2.0` and really I do not need any other library because I'm not doing something complex!